# Can't get SSL to work for a Secure Websocket connection

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, websocket

I'm new to Python but have to build a Websocket API for work.
The website of the websockets module says that this code should work for secure websocket connections (https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html)

However, I cannot get the provided code to work..

```
import websockets
import asyncio
import pathlib
import ssl

ssl_context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_CLIENT)
ssl_context.load_verify_locations(pathlib.Path(__file__).with_name('localhost.pem'))
```

I get the error:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/Applications/Python 3.7/apii.py", line 7, in module>
    ssl_context.load_verify_locations(pathlib.Path(__ file__).with_name('localhost.pem'))

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Could you help me out?

PS. I do not get the idea of this ssl_context code at all. Could somebody explain the logic behind it, please?

Comment: *"I do not get the idea of this ssl_context code at all."* - I consider this question as too broad. My guess is that you need a basic understanding of how SSL/TLS works   first - and there are many resources online which explain this. As for *"No such file or directory"* - likely the given file does not exist as the error message says.

Comment: This piece of code is provided by the websockets library creators, so I guess the file should be there by default. I cannot find such file on my hard drive... Could you please answer only if you could help. Your answer does not give me any clarification to the problem.

Comment: *"so I guess the file should be there by default."* - wrong guess. This piece of code is only example code which shows basic usage. And, in front of this example code you'll find *"Refer to the documentation of the ssl module for configuring the context securely"*. Thus, it is expected to have some understanding of ssl and how it is used in Python already, this is not specific to websockets. Please take your time to study the [documentation of the ssl module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html) first and also learn the basics concept of SSL/TLS.

Comment: Understood. Thanks for the info!

I will appreciate if there is anyone that could give me an example code for getting the ssl context running (even if it is not "securely").

Comment: Figured out that with the following code I just ignore the SSL verification, because going through and understanding all the SSL documentation is a bit much for a beginner. Here is the code:

import ssl

ctx = ssl_context = ssl.create_default_context()

ctx.check_hostname = False

ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

Comment: If you switch all validation off because you don't understand it - maybe you shouldn't use TLS (`wss://`) in the first place but just use plain websockets without TLS (`ws://`). The protection you get with this is about this same as with switch off all validation.

Comment: I don't use/disable the SSL for fun, the server does not allow me to connect otherwise..

Comment: The validation of the server certificate is done at the client side. It is not the server which does not let you connect but the client fails to connect since it has not the necessary trust anchor to  validate that the server is the expected one. Clearly, you are missing a basic understanding of how TLS works and I only hope that you get this understanding and fix your code before your code ever gets used in some relevant way - because currently it is an [obvious security issue](https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/295.html).

Comment: I was here with the purpose to get help for the issue but got nothing better than a google search would have given me,,, the advise "maybe you shouldn't use TLS (wss://) in the first place but just use plain websockets without TLS (ws://)" doesn't work and doesn't make sense... I am very disappointed from the answer of my first question here... Thought it was a community with multiple contributors instead  I get worse response than google with the only suggestion for how to improve my code making it crash...

Comment: "the client fails to connect since it has not the necessary trust anchor to validate that the server is the expected one" why would you give me an advise if the client would fail to connect? Knowing how it works obviously does not help with making it work...

Answer (score 7):

I test websockets from docker containers. where I have NAT ips (cant use LetsEncrypt), and no * domain certificate. If I test directly in Firefox it works fine without any certificate. So disabling the SSL for testing purpose inside a firewall should be allowed.

Extract:

```
import asyncio
import websockets
import ssl
:    
ssl_context = ssl.create_default_context()
ssl_context.check_hostname = False
ssl_context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

async def logIn(uri, myjson):
    async with websockets.connect(uri) as websocket:
        await websocket.send(myjson)

async def logIn(uri, myjson):
    async with websockets.connect(uri, ssl=ssl_context) as websocket:
        await websocket.send(myjson)
        resp = await websocket.recv()
        print(resp)

myurl = f"wss://{args.server}:{args.port}"
print("connection url:{}".format(myurl))

# logdef is the json string I send in
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(
    logIn(myurl, logdef)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Late answer but maybe still interesting for others.
The documentation ([1](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html#secure-example)) for this specific example says:

> This client needs a context because the server uses a self-signed certificate. A client connecting to a secure WebSocket server with a valid certificate (i.e. signed by a CA that your Python installation trusts) can simply pass ssl=True to connect() instead of building a context.

So if the server-certificate from the server you want to access has a valid certificate just do the following:

```
uri = "wss://server_you_want_to_connect_to_endpoint"
async with websockets.connect(uri, ssl=True) as websocket:
    and so on ...
```